# How to check for a binary to decimal program if the input is indeed a binary number (only 1s and 0s)?

Tags: c, binary

wanted to write a program to convert a binary number to a decimal one, but I wanted to make sure, that if the user enters something like lets say: 250, there should be an error message and to ask to enter a real binary number.

How could I do this, I really cant find a solution. I have managed to block characters like "a" or so, but this one is very tricky!

Thanks for any help!

I tried it with this code, but the if statement seems to be always false, any explanation possible why this is so?

```
void isBinary(char s[MAX])
```

{

int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)

```
{




    if(s[i] == 0 || s[i] == 1)

    {

        continue;


    }

    else {

        printf("Error!\n");
        break;


        }






}
```

}

Comment: are you using c or c++? what have you tried? where did you get stuck? please show a [mre]

Comment: You really should post the language you're using.  For C++, a single `std::all_of` call is all that's necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I have typed it in: in normal C

Comment: I tried it with this function, unfortunately it doesnt work. Can you help me out finding the error (I am very new to coding)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in a function to verify your data, but it seems pretty simple, something like this:

```
string line;

getline(cin, line);
for (char c: line) {
    if (c != '0' && c != '1') {
        cout << "Please input binary only." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check an Integer if it contains certain digits also?

Answer (score 0):

## The code

Here is an example using C without any dynamic allocating:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    _Bool haserror = 0;
    int result; // the number
    do
    {
        result = 0; // reset the number
        haserror = 0; // reset error
        _Bool isEmpty = 1; // this means that the user just hit enter and didn't specify any number
        char c; // we process the string character by character
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') // read until the newline (If you are using Windows, you might need to change this, because Windows uses "\r\n" for newlines)
        {
            isEmpty = 0; // there is some imput

            if (c != '0' && c != '1')
            {
                printf("This is unacceptable!\n");
                while (getchar() != '\n'); // clear out the garbage

                haserror = 1; // there's an error, loop
                break;
            }

            result <<= 1; // the actual conversion from binary to decimal, using advanced binary operations
            result |= (c - '0');
        }

        if (isEmpty)
        {
            printf("Nothing is unacceptable, too!\n");
            haserror = 1;
        }
    } while (haserror); // loop until there isn't any error

    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

This lacks some features (Windows newlines, `EOF` handling), but shows the main logic.

## The math

Let's say we have already read the number `1010` and re need to add the number `1` to the end. We will need to create space for the new number, so we shift it to the left by one.

```c
Before: 1010
After:  10100
```

Then we get the actual number with `(c - '0')`. If `c` is `'0'`, than `'0' - '0'` is `0`. If `c` is `'1'`, than its value in ASCII is `49`, minus the value of '0', which is `48` in ASCII. `49 - 48 = 1`, so `'1'` will be converted to `1`, which is correct.

Then we OR it.

```c
10100 OR
00001
-----
10101
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the well explained example. Is there a way to make it way simpler, and shorter?

Comment: This solution does not use any fixed-size buffers nor dynamic allocations. This is a big advantage over other implementations. With buffers you need to first read the data and then process data. You access this data twice (or more). With this implementation, you do the processing while reading data, so you read the data only one time, which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

## BAD answer

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Bool validate(const char * c);

int main()
{
    char buffer[10]; // very ugly fixed-size buffer
    while (1)
    {
        if (scanf("%9s", buffer) == EOF) // EOF means reading error, propably not recoverable
            return 1;

        while ((readError = getchar()) != '\n' && readError != EOF); // clear out the garbage
        if (readError == EOF) // there is no more data to read
            return 1;
        if (!validate(buffer)) // main work is done via strtoul(), but it returns 0 on error, so there isn't any way to distinguish bad imput from user typing 0, so we need to check manually
        {
            printf("This is unacceptable!\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%ld\n", strtoul(buffer, 0, 2)); // strtoul converts the string to unsigned long
        break;
    }
}

_Bool validate(const char * c)
{
    for (; *c != 0; c++) // iterate through all character, checking if they're '0' or '1'
    {
        if (*c != '0' && *c != '1')
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This code processes data three times (`scanf()` reads it, `validate()` validates it and `strtoul()` extracts the number). My other solution is longer but better.

This time I added `EOF` checking.

Again there might be some complications with Windows newlines.